# I am installing Open-edx devstack for local machine through Ubuntu vm. but getting the following error after running the command make dev.provision

Tags: devstack, openedx, edx

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSbWA.png)

I already installed pavar (python).
**Error classified as Syntax error.**

[these are the files and directories created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVLNn.png)

Comment: What version you are using? If possible add your installation steps.

Comment: I follow this documentation for installation with ubuntu 20.04 version
https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/open-release-hawthorn.master/installation/install_devstack.html

Comment: Hope you have checked the prerequisites also.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.